# If you pass around a stateful object between reactive lambda constructs do you need to care about thread visibility?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, reactor

Say we are using RxJava or Reactor, we have object which contains couple properties which can be mutated through setters. Say that some operations we run on different thread pools. We use this state object in our pipeline multiple times and change its properties. Do we still need "volatile" to ensure cached version isn't returned? Or there is a mechanism together with sequential nature of pipeline which ensure that modified object returned through .flatMap for example ? Do we need to have this object immutable and recreated each time on modification?

Comment: are multiple "pipelines" modifying this object? or is the object only used in a single pipeline?

Comment: @WilliamReed sorry, eventually replied under your answer. Object is used in single long non-parallel pipeline and some tasks are dispatched to different tps. Object maybe modified in each stage, prior being dispatched to another tp for another stage processing. Hopefully it makes sense :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case where you are modifying a single object in multiple pipelines consider the following:

```java
// this example is in Kotlin but should be fairly analagous to java
fun main() {
    var count = 0

    Flowable.range(0, 1000)
        // splits the stream into "parallel pipelines"
        .parallel()
        .runOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .doAfterNext { count += 1 }
        // merge back into a single pipeline
        .sequential()
        .subscribe()

    println(count)
}
```

The results of this will vary but on my computer it prints anything from `600` - `850`

For the sake of the example the two ways we can go about fixing this are by using an `AtomicInteger` in place of the `Int` used. Even better would be to not store any count variable and just perform the addition on each parallel process and then combine the results after we go back to one stream with `sequential` but I am not sure that would apply to your question.

To recap, if you are modifying any number of objects but only in one pipeline at a time then you don't have to worry about threading issues as the modifications are limited to a single thread. If it is split up into multiple pipelines *at the same time* then you do have to worry about this just as you normally would with any mutli threading application. The solution could involve using locks, or synchronized objects available in Java, or there may be a more reactive way to avoid these issues (like only processing in one pipeline at a time), however it is hard to say without a specific example.

Comment: the key part which I still don't know what happens is when you have one pipeline, but you switch pipeline context to another thread, this is not parallel from the perspective of the work to be done, as only one ever thread works on part of pipeline. So the threads must pass on the context , they don't share it per say, it's a step transition and I am unsure what happens in this case. So if we take your example, remove .parallel and add more computation along with thread switch. Or I can try this myself :-P

Comment: @Aubergine if you switch threads with `observeOn` in a single pipeline, we are only ever modifying it in a single thread at a time. You likely don't have to worry about race conditions then, however marking variables in use `volatile` may be useful.  I am not sure if rxjava does anything under the hood with how it passes around objects so it may not be needed at all. But definately try it out in a simple example

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have state that is read and written from different threads you need to use one of the synchronization mechanisms to ensure that a thread "sees" the effects of other threads actions.

Without proper synchronization it is possible that threads see partial effects or effects in unexpected order.

see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5 for more details.

So you should ensure that all access to your state object is correctly synchronized. Alternatively you could avoid state modification within your pipeline. Use immutable data structures instead.